# yii2 Undefined variable in form

Tags: yii2, undefined-variable

When running the code:

```
return $this->render('update', [
   'model' => $model,
   'stok' => $stok
   ]);
```

I get an error related to undefined variable:

> PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable:
>   stok'

My form is as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
   <?= $form->field($stok, 'harga_jual1')->textInput(['id' => 'hargaRetail'])->label('Harga Retail') ?>
</div>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: you missed **update.php** from where `_form.php` rendered. add `'stok' => $stok` there also.

Answer (score 3):

check it out and follow the render what would be do! 
controller -> render update.php -> _form.php

readd below in  _form.php

```
return $this->render('_form', [
   'model' => $model,
   'stok' => $stok
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on the update.php, is it already set 
this block

```
return $this->render('_form', [
   'model' => $model,
   'stok' => $stok
]);
```

Usually from actionUpdate controller it's will be render update.php then inside it will be render _form.php, so the $stok variable must be set too in the update.php